# Circular Progress bar in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Any idea how to create this. I am using ProgressRingBar but it has some limitations. I want to show progress in percentage also inside the ring. Which is not possible with this
 Any other way to achieve this for both Android and iOS platforms

Comment: I think syncfusion free control will be helpfull. https://www.syncfusion.com/xamarin-ui-controls/xamarin-progressbar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got this working:

```
<control:ProgressRing Margin = "165,0,-20,40" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" HeightRequest= "40" RingProgressColor="#ebf5e4" RingBaseColor="LightGray" RingThickness="25" AnimatedProgress="{Binding Progress}" AnimationEasing="2" />
                   <Label x:Name="LabelProgress" Margin = "200,0,-20,40" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" FontSize="Micro" Text="{Binding ProgressPercentage}" WidthRequest="50" HeightRequest="20" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" />
```

I use a label with a ProgressRing to show the percentage of progress. This works for me.

Comment: I'm using ProgressRing but on iOS 13 the progress bar appears flat.

Comment: I am not sure which version I used but this was the only thing that worked for me. You can try using some extension in Xamarin